# HW/SW audit Anyone know how to get Belarc Advisor to run remotely via psexec?

Tags: windows, command-line

Trying to do a quick hardware and software audit on my network. 
I have a remote system that I copied belarc advisor over to. 
I have pstools on my local system. 
I am using the command line:

psexec -d \remotecomputername -u myusername -p mypassword cmd c:\Belarc\BelarcAdvisor\BelarcAdvisor.exe

I get

cmd started on remotecomputername with process id 11184

then nothing.

When I start Belarc Advisor on my local system, it prompts for various responses.
Why am I not seeing the choices from the remote machine?
What else do I need to do to get the Belarc to run, etc.?

Comment: How are you sure that the command is not working correctly and suddenly showing the results on the screen of the remote computer?

Answer (score 1):

PSEXEC only redirects output for command-line utilities. Belarc Advisor uses a GUI for choosing options, then outputs its report to an HTML file. Therefore, PSEXEC will not be able to show you the interface for Belarc Advisor when it is running on the remote machine - in fact, it is possible that the utility may be instead popping up on the current user's desktop, on the remote machine, unexpectedly.

Answer (score -1):

I monitored the processes on the remote computer and realized psexec was spawning the installation for belarc advisor because the remote computer did not have belarc advisor installed as I originally thought.
I installed belarc advisor on the remote computer, restarted and tried again, but it kept prompting for various inputs and their proprietary bcx file in the command line, so I went back the the belarc site so I can get something going asap.
The belarc advisor managed software works out to about $5US per machine to have much more sophisticated HW/SW reporting than what the free, standalone version offers, so I will go with that option instead.
   Thanks for all of the fantastic help guys.